how to make an unstacking on scroll animation
Does anyone know how to make this animation at the bottom of this website?:
enter link description here

It's just a matter of using position: sticky but this time sticking it to the bottom: 0, and stacking them on top of one another using z-index. A little trial and error yields this example:


body {
  background: #3f3f3f;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #3f3f3f;
  z-index: 4;
}

.box1 {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: purple;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box2 {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: darkslateblue;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box3 {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>hello world</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in egestas nulla. In sit amet blandit sapien. Fusce venenatis purus ac vulputate venenatis. Aliquam vulputate sem nec neque rutrum, ut vulputate ex lobortis. Quisque porta dignissim gravida.
      Vivamus feugiat lobortis risus eget interdum. Mauris dignissim felis vel est porta, sed imperdiet mauris porta. Cras id sollicitudin ex. Mauris sed dapibus mi, eu rutrum risus. Suspendisse eu mi varius, ultricies ex ut, condimentum arcu. Ut non
      nibh a elit efficitur sollicitudin ut non tellus. Proin ac fermentum velit. Praesent ac odio vitae sapien volutpat consequat sit amet in nisl. Praesent elementum nisl eros, vitae congue ante placerat a. In tincidunt risus fringilla, sagittis mi
      eu, mattis mauris.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in egestas nulla. In sit amet blandit sapien. Fusce venenatis purus ac vulputate venenatis. Aliquam vulputate sem nec neque rutrum, ut vulputate ex lobortis. Quisque porta dignissim gravida.
      Vivamus feugiat lobortis risus eget interdum. Mauris dignissim felis vel est porta, sed imperdiet mauris porta. Cras id sollicitudin ex. Mauris sed dapibus mi, eu rutrum risus. Suspendisse eu mi varius, ultricies ex ut, condimentum arcu. Ut non
      nibh a elit efficitur sollicitudin ut non tellus. Proin ac fermentum velit. Praesent ac odio vitae sapien volutpat consequat sit amet in nisl. Praesent elementum nisl eros, vitae congue ante placerat a. In tincidunt risus fringilla, sagittis mi
      eu, mattis mauris.</p>
    <br>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box box2">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box box3">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
  </div>

</body>




Hello,
I had never used the static position in this sense, very inspiring thank you.
The problem is that the structure of my project does not allow me to use it as I would like because there is the footer which is below the 'main' tag which prevents me from using this solution.
finally I do not see how to do if I want to keep this structure of html which is better for seo.
I would have liked to ask you another question by showing you the structure of my HTML but apparently the post has been closed. Is it possible to reopen it?

if you can create [mre] then it might be worth to start a new question.
